# Invalid HTML response when using Java webclient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Am working with Reactive Webclient in Spring, and am having some difficulty determining why am getting the below response format from a GET request:

```
�\jj��T{�8��?�t(O�"V$�@��)���5�����~?��J�t"��   ��EEΕ7�b��,�u�i�=��k���3�ӡ�������m,��ꔁu�T낙*��{�Ǳ�l�`����{� ��M��+mB)��E{�UtG���ʘJ#ؠ�]j<u�?6�`h���.����n��?�ʋ*��#%�w'<L��d�Ly����R�>���$�O�����—o�}�� �����v���{���?����r�;
```

This is the code am using below for the request:

```
return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(URI.create(uri))
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML)
                .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

WebClient setup is as below:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
                .followRedirect(true)
                .secure()
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeoutMillis));

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
                .build();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like response is encoded, probably gzipped, especially that you have declared to the server, that you are able to decode gzip, deflate and br encodings with

`Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br`

You can remove `.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")` and see if the server is willing to send you a plain text response.